# VSTO Outlook Folder webview and unread items

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I need to create a Outlook custom Folder (inside Inbox) with a WebView. Its simple, I just need to set:

```
Outlook.MAPIFolder customFolder = (Outlook.MAPIFolder)inBox.Folders.Add("My Folder", Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
customFolder.WebViewOn = true;
customFolder.WebViewURL = "http://localhost:51170/";
customFolder.ShowItemCount = Outlook.OlShowItemCount.olShowUnreadItemCount;
```

But now I need to add small number like unread items in folder. The idea its like and email folder with unread emails, but when user clicks open a website.

Is it possible?

Comment: Doesn't ShowItemCount property work for you if you have items in that folder (you can still create them programmatically)?

Comment: yes i can create, but if i create items, the webview is turn false

Comment: Can you turn it back on after creating the items?

Comment: after creating the item